# How do I get the compiler to see my Framework module.modulemap umbrella header?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, module, frameworks

I am building a framework with mixed Objective-C and Swift source files.
I've created my own module map file named module.modulemap.

My problem is that the compiler compiles only my umbrella header file when I put in the absolute path:

[image: Not working!]

[image: Working, Yeah!]

How do I get the compiler/Xcode to see the header file?

Comment: Have you tried marking your TestObject.h file as "Public" instead of "Project" in the target membership? Try to see if it helps, if not yet done.

Comment: Yes, TestObject.h is marked as public.

Comment: I see. What about swift search paths under build settings? And also is there any specific reason why you even need module.modulemap file? To make it clear, to have interoperability of Swift/Objective-C & C within the same framework project, you just need one umbrella header file and correct build settings (see more info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html under "Importing Objective-C into Swift" and "Importing Swift into Objective-C" sections)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've found the issue. (Or one of them).  It seems that to be able to use an umbrella header, the header must be an actual header file.  In this case I was just using the only header file in the project, which also had a .m file.

My solution was to create an actual UmbrellaHeader.h file with the following contents:

```
#ifndef UmbrellaHeader_h
#define UmbrellaHeader_h

#include "TestObject.h"

#endif /* UmbrellaHeader_h */
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: If your project has its Headers phase *before* Compile Sources and you try to create a mixed Objective-C/Swift framework, you can see Swift compiler errors about the umbrella header being missing. If you remove/rename all .swift files the project will build fine, then putting them back it will build a second time, but a clean build fails.

Just move the Headers phase earlier in the build process and it should work.